Would investing in an index tracking S&P500 increase my unsystematic risk?
While learning about investing, I came across the term systematic and unsystematic risk. From this website, unsystematic risk is defined as "Unsystematic Risk, or “idiosyncratic risk”, refers to the risk inherent to a particular company or industry, rather than from the broader economy and financial markets."
However, while going over S&P500 companies from here, I see that tech companies have atleast 25% of the entire weight. While the tech world is doing really great, wouldn't this badly affect the diversification process?
In addition, I am a software engineer myself and am not sure if holding index funds related to my field of work is a good idea.

Vanguard's broad market ETF is VTI. Their S&P 500 ETF is VOO.

The correlation between VTI and VOO is 0.99, which is considered to be high.

https://portfolioslab.com/tools/stock-comparison/VTI/VOO
Calling 0.99 "high" is an understatement. Investing in VOO rather than VTI is increasing your unsystemic risk by about 1%, or 2% if you're measuring by variance rather than standard deviation. They both have an expense ratio of 3 bp, so if you're worried about unsystemic risk, go ahead and buy VTI rather than VOO. But it's not a large difference either way.
The reason VOO has a large amount of value invested in tech stocks is because tech stocks are a large portion of the overall stock market value. Any ETF that tries to minimize unsystemic risk is going to be invested heavily in tech stocks.
The Efficient Market Hypothesis says that if the market is risk averse, stocks will be priced in a way that your risk-adjusted returns are maximized by having a cap-weighted investments.
In Nosjack's answer, they claim that equal weight funds reduce unsystemic risk. This is false. Systemic risk is, by definition, the risk one would have with cap weighted investment. Any deviation from that is introducing unsystemic risk. On top of that, equal weight funds tend to have around seven times the expense ratios.

In short, yes. Popular S&P500 funds like VOO have over 30% weight in the Information Technology category. To make things worse, in the case of VOO 25% is made up of the top five stocks (which are all tech). As tech stocks have increased over the past couple decades, more people have expressed concern about too much concentration in one industry.
To address this, you can include other index funds to get more mid or small cap exposure, or utilize a total market fund (but that might still have over 20% tech stocks). Another option is an equal weight S&P500 fund/ETF. Each of these options would obviously change the total return. But that is a natural trade-off for reducing risk.
That being said, like mhoran_psprep alluded to, the tech industry is relatively diverse. Some focus on consumer electronics or enterprise services, computer hardware or communication infrastructure, etc. So the risk may not be quite as bad as you think.


I see that tech companies have at least 25% of the entire weight.
While the tech world is doing really great, wouldn't this badly affect
the diversification process?
In addition, I am a software engineer myself and am not sure if
holding index funds related to my field of work is a good idea.

Not all software engineers work for tech companies. There are engineers that work for companies that write boring software that run doctors office, schools, and grocery stores. They write programs that are used by auditors, accountants, and non-profits. They create applications that are used to issue drivers licenses, manage restaurant reservation systems, and run payment networks. Some work for the government.
There have been software engineers since the 1950's. The senior engineer that I met when I graduated college fought in  World War II. He write code for some of the earliest US satellites, and helped develop GPS. If he had been born 50 years later he would have written code to run on a smart phone.
The list of companies in the S&P 500 isn't fixed. It changes every year. The percentage of companies that are involved in a Moon based economy or Mars based economy in a few decades might be different from the number today.
